# Assign simple Array to Object Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which contains class Objects. How can I add objects to Array?

```
 private Rule[] ruleList;
```

Here, I made an Object of Rule Class, say

```
Rule myRule = new Rule();
```

Now I added this to a simple simple

```
   ArrayList<Rule> myArray = new ArrayList<Rule>();
   myArray.add(myRule);
```

where myRule is object of RuleClass.

How can assign myArray to ruleList?

Comment: Don't call it a `ruleList`, it will confuse you. Call it `rules`.

Comment: I posted wrong question by mistake, I have edited it, now please see this.

Comment: Based on this question and your previous one it would appear you don't understand the difference between an array and a class that implements the `List` interface. I would highly suggest a good beginners book on Java or at the very least reading the tutorials provided by Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

> How can assign `myArray` to `ruleList`?

You cannot assign `myArray` *to* `ruleList`, but you can assign `myArray` *from* `ruleList` like this:

```
ruleList = myArray.toArray(new Rule[0]);
```

Note: You named an array `ruleList` and a list `myArray`. You should switch the names around for better clarity.